# MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen not working with adjusted VC hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

We are setting up our app hierarchy dynamically so their is no persistent Tab/Nav view controllers, its dependent on the database content.

We have recently added a feature which opens a VC to allow the user to select which database (layout/content) to display however this has caused out video playback to break when in fullscreen.

Previously (and currently) we playback videos within a Nav Controller (in a Tab) with a custom control overlay. This all works fine.

On the control bar there is a fullscreen button which fires the MPC standard fullscreen mode. Previously it worked fine, but now the sound continues playing in the background but no movie is displayed or an overlaying layer - I can still see our tab bar, which is clickable.

Could this be something to do with the order of views on the window? If so how can I pick up the correct one to bring it forward?

Comment: from memory the full screen player is added as a subview of rootViewController.view, you could try implementing didAddSubview: in that view

Answer (score 0):

You can bring any subview to forward `[view_1 bringSubviewToFront:view_2];`

Comment: Yes thanks I know this, I've just checked the Windows subview array and it doesnt seem to change when flicking to fullscreen mode

Answer (score 0):

We found out the problem....

It was that we weren't setting the window.rootViewController in the end to the new view controller, we were only adding its view to the windows subviews

This fixed both this (just after I had written a custom fullscreen mode) and also problems we were having with rotation